# Как вызвать импорт?

Tags: javascript

Подключаю функции:

```js
import func1 from './func1';
import func2 from './func2';
import func3 from './func3';

...
import funcN from './funcN';

const funs = Object.freeze({
  func1,
  func2,
  func3,

  ...
});

export default function getF(name) {
  return funs[name].call(this);
}
```

Как это сделать без дополнительного объекта `funs`?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить if либо switch

if (name == 'func1')
return func1.call(this);

....

что то подобное, только вот смысл?

Comment: Вариант, но тогда лучше `switch`. Вы подобных проблем не решали в своих проектах? Как вы реализовывали фабрику методов?

Comment: Вот посмотрите пример со switch https://www.google.com/amp/s/webdevblog.ru/shablony-proektirovaniya-v-javascript/amp/